# Vim: How to place two newlines and then put cursor in insert mode on first newline using a shortkey?

Tags: vim

I want to achieve the following using a key shortcut in Vim:

```
hi
| <-my cursor is here
there
```

press shift+o

```
hi
| <-my cursor is here

there
```

press enter

```
hi

| <-my cursor is here

there
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use a mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following mapping should be enough

```
nn <Leader>o O<CR><Esc>
```

Note

- `<Leader>` is a "special key" that you can set (cf. `:h <Leader>`)
- you can choose your own key combination to trigger the mapping, not necessarily `<Leader>o`
- `<Esc>` is to go back to normal mode. Given How `O` and `o` work maybe you want to remain in insert mode? If so, remove `<Esc>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `:help mapping`. Mapping keys is when you *map* one key or several keys to act like other keys. In your case, this is a map you might use:

`nnoremap (your chosen key(s)) O<CR>`

This means that in normal mode, when you hit `your chosen key(s)`, vim will instead act as though you hit `O` and then `<CR>`. `<CR>` is how you indicate the 'Enter/Return' key.

This is assuming you meant you wanted to start from normal mode.